# MySQL: tags and searching

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know if my SQL query is correct and will be fast for a large amount of data.

SQL structure:

```
TABLE: products
id            integer auto_increment
name          text
description   text

TABLE: tags
id      integer auto_increment
title   text

TABLE: products_tags
product_id   integer
tag_id       integer
```

For example I want to find all the products that have a tag with id 1 and 2 or 3.

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT products.*
FROM products
LEFT JOIN products_tags ON products_tags.product_id = products.id
WHERE (products_tags.tag_id = 1 AND products_tags.tag_id = 2) OR products_tags.tag_id = 3
```

I know I can use this query but I think it will be very slow for large data:

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products
WHERE products.id IN (SELECT products_tags.product_id FROM products_tags WHERE (products_tags.tag_id = 1 AND products_tags.tag_id = 2) OR products_tags.tag_id = 3)
```

Should I change something?

Comment: If you have right indices, the second solution will be quite fast - because accessing the `product_id`s for a given list of `tag_id`s uses an index for `tag_id` and requesting a list of products by their `product_id` uses an index for `products.id` where you have lesser number of records then joining all together and *then* filtering.

Comment: A given value can never equal two other given values at the same time. That would be a quantum leap. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (and you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your current And clause isn't going to work:

```
products_tags.tag_id = 1 AND products_tags.tag_id = 2
```

The tag ID cannot be both 1 and 2, that's unpossible. Instead you want it to be in the set of possible values.

If you're filtering on the products_tags table and not allowing for nulls then You should make it an `INNER JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN`.

Adding a `GROUP BY` clause is typically far faster than attempting to use WHERE EXISTS or over complicating things.

```
SELECT P.*
FROM products AS P
INNER JOIN products_tags AS PT
    ON PT.product_id = P.id
WHERE PT.tag_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY P.id
```

If your speed is still slow run it with `EXPLAIN` in front like so:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT P.*
FROM products AS P
INNER JOIN products_tags AS PT
    ON PT.product_id = P.id
WHERE PT.tag_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY P.id
```

This should say that it's using an index:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------------+---------+--------------------+------+---------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------------+---------+--------------------+------+---------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | PT    | index  | idxProductTag | idxProductTag | 8       | NULL               |    7 | Using where; Using index; |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | P     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY       | 4       | test.PT.product_id |    1 |                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------------+---------+--------------------+------+---------------------------+
```

If not you can create one for the purpose:

```
 CREATE INDEX idxProductTag ON product_tags (product_id, tag_id);
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT: It appears I was wrong about the query's goal, this should be more accurate:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM products AS P
INNER JOIN ( -- Sub Query
    SELECT
        product_id
    FROM
        products_tags
    WHERE tag_id = 3 -- Any where the tag_id is 3 should be returned
    UNION
    SELECT
        product_id
    FROM
        products_tags
    WHERE tag_id IN (1,2) -- And any where the tag ID is 1 or 2
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING COUNT(1) = 2 -- With exactly 2 rows :D
) AS PT
    ON PT.product_id = P.id
GROUP BY P.id
```

Comment: Ok, you're right and your query is pretty fast (~0,1s for 350k products and 180 tags) BUT this fetch all product that has tag 1 OR 2 OR 3. I want to fetch products that has tag  (1 AND 2) OR 3

Comment: @Fafu Oh, I didn't get that from the question, give me a bit and I'll correct the post, sorry.

Comment: @Fafu Could you check the edit, see if that meets your requirements, it will be slower though, but I can't imagine it'd be too slow.

Comment: Sorry, but that query is incredibly slow ;) I added "LIMIT 5" and it was executing for ~50s

Comment: @Fafu, Do me a favour here and run explain on it and post the output to pastebin or something similar, I'm really curious to see why that is.